# How to get coordinates of corners of an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to get the four corner points or coordinates of an image. How can get I get them in MatLab?

Comment: What kind of image is this? Please post an example or a detailed description.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608428/finding-edge-and-corner-values-of-an-image-in-matlab, here it is explained clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the coordinates of the image corners when you plot the image in an axes using either [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html) or [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html)/[IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html), then here is how you can find them:

- If you plot the image without specifying ranges:

  ```
  image(img);
  imshow(img);
  ```

  Then `img` is plotted on an axes with the pixels centered at the values `1:size(img,2)` horizontally and `1:size(img,1)` vertically. Since these values represent the pixel centers, and the pixel size is 1, then the image extends half a pixel past the above ranges in every direction. The extents of the image are therefore:

  ```
  xmin = 0.5;
  xmax = size(img,2)+0.5;
  ymin = 0.5;
  ymax = size(img,1)+0.5;
  ```

  From which you can get your corner coordinates `[xmin ymin]`, `[xmin ymax]`, `[xmax ymin]`, and `[xmax ymax]`.
- If you specify ranges for plotting, such as:

  ```
  image([x1 x2],[y1 y2],img);
  ```

  You may think that these limits you specify are the *edges* of the plotted image, but they are actually the extents of the *pixel centers*, so yet again the true extent of the plotted image is half a pixel further in every direction. The pixel size in each direction can be calculated as follows:

  ```
  dx = abs(x2-x1)/size(img,2);
  dy = abs(y2-y1)/size(img,1);
  ```

  And the extents of the image are therefore:

  ```
  xmin = min(x1,x2)-0.5*dx;
  xmax = max(x1,x2)+0.5*dx;
  ymin = min(y1,y2)-0.5*dy;
  ymax = max(y1,y2)+0.5*dy;
  ```

  From which you can again easily get your corner coordinates.